# Fonts screwy in toolhints, Select list items on multiple browsers and many apps

Tags: fonts

I have a fairly new installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3. Everything was working flawlessly, then suddenly** I noticed fonts started freaking out in Chrome & Firefox (see images at end). The problem only appears to affect ***some*** toolhints and select list items text ("popovers"), and not just in the browser window, but throughout the entire main window.

Further investigation revealed this text rendering issue is also happening for ***many applications***: Qt5's (Stellarium, Google Earth), Chrome (Chrome, Chromium), and Mozilla (Firefox, Thunderbird) as well as other apps I use like Gimp and VLC. The Gnome desktop and related tools seem totally fine, as well as many standard bundled applications like LibreOffice, Calculator etc.

I've searched for reports of this kind of problem, but haven't found anything that sounds quite like it. I have tried changing Font settings in Gnome Tweaks tool to no avail.

How should I go about troubleshooting the problem and, ultimately, find a solution? I really don't know much about fonts or font rendering on Linux/Ubuntu, and I haven't found anything to point me in the right direction or I could probably figure it out myself.

** It seems like this started after a recent Ubuntu software update, but it's possible I messed something up or something I installed did, but I can't think of what could be affecting so many applications in this very specific way. I'm hoping it's something obvious to someone and simple to fix!

Thank you,
Mike

```
-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27
Distribution        : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
-Computer-
Processor       : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
Memory      : 8135MB (4819MB used)
Machine Type        : Desktop
Operating System        : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- VGA -
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
-Display-
Resolution      : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.3.0-26-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
```

### SCREEN SHOTS

[Seen on Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LlAZ.png) --
[In Gimp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4lbk.png) --
[Closeup in Gimp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziEou.png) (See the font is rounded and sheared horizontally) -- 
[But not all hovers do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4bTQ.png) -- [Current Tweak settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h0ix.jpg) (I've tried changing everything here and it doesn't help)

(I had a hard time capturing images in some programs as the focus collapses when I issue a print screen...but you get the idea)

Comment: One thing I noted going through the dpkg log is a kernel update about the same time I started seeing this font rendering problem--from 5.0.0.37.95 to 5.3.0-26-generic--probably right after the system got rebooted. Also, I checked from a fresh new user account... Same problem!! So I haven't tried resetting dconf for my home account because it probably won't help. Again this is a Sapphire Technology Radeon HD 6450 1GB DDR3 with kernel Radeon driver. I haven't touched any of the settings there.

Comment: Just found this very similar sounding problem in Linux Mint Forums: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=309976

Comment: I tried rolling back to the previous two versions in grub--problem was still there. Tried  "apt install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all" suggested as a viable fix in the above Mint Forum thread and it didn't help either. This is now beyond my level of troubleshooting and the problem is really obnoxious.

Comment: UPDATE: A new software update was waiting for me today. Installed, rebooted, and problem gone! Yay!! Something to do with xserver video hwe bug, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: A new software update was waiting for me today. Installed, rebooted, and the problem is gone. Yay!! Something to do with xserver video hwe bug in the previous update, as I understand.